# Create a catalog for Windows Search Service programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-search, indexing-service

I've been reading through the Windows Search Service documentation and samples for more than a day now, and while I've learned a lot, I still feel no closer to the answers I was looking for.

The context is I have a web app that uses Indexing Service for full-text searching.  Because this is no longer supported and has loads of bugs, I want to migrate away from indexing service to Windows Search Service.

In the indexing service solution, I create a catalog for the documents I want to index (instead of using the default system index).  Specifically, I use CIODMLib.AdminIndexServer objects to programmatically create catalogs as-needed.

That's all dandy until I need to migrate to WSS.  At most I can find only the occasional allusion to catalogs in the WSS documentation and nothing about an API for creating them in say C#.  So, the first question: **Is there a way to create WSS catalogs programmatically?**

As a followup question, **is it even necessary to create multiple catalogs?  Can I safely use SCOPE() (as in SQL Syntax) on the SystemIndex to performantly make full-text queries?**

Comment: Note: Using SCOPE() only provides a small portion of the functionality that the Indexing Service catalogs did.  In Indexing Services, it was easy to control file/folder inclusions, file/folder exclusions, indexing schedules, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue regarding full-text queries. However, I can answer that SCOPE can be used to limit the query, eliminating the need for multiple catalogs.

```
objRecordSet.Open "SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemTypeText, System.Size FROM SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file:c:/users'", objConnection
```

This is taken almost word-for-word from the vbscript sample on TechNet.